# Immutable version of EnumSet

Tags: java, collections, set, immutability

I can't find an [Immutable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html) version of [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).  Two questions:

Can I use Enums in a normal Guava ImmutableSet?

If I can, what are some benefits/drawbacks of using an ImmutableSet instead of the EnumSet?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Are you looking for [`Sets.immutableEnumSet`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#immutableEnumSet-java.lang.Iterable-) (Guava) perhaps?

> Returns an immutable set instance containing the given enum elements. Internally, the returned set will be backed by an EnumSet.
>
> The iteration order of the returned set follows the enum's iteration order, not the order in which the elements appear in the given collection.

Comment: The hyperlink is broken. Can you please correct it. It looks like there is an enhancement in Java 8 to support. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145048

Comment: @gurubelli: Fixed the link; don't have time to investigate the Java 8 situation right now, but hopefully your comment will be enough for anyone looking.

Comment: There appears to have been no movement on that issue, so this is still the best solution as of Java 20.

Answer (score 12):

Is there a problem with this?

```
Collections.unmodifiableSet(myEnumSet);
```

Comment: In some cases Immutable is better than simply Unmodifiable.  Unmodifiable collections are not guaranteed to never change their contents, they only guarantee that YOU can't change the contents.

Comment: The answer returns a `Set<Enumtype>` not a `EnumSet<Enumtype>`. And the result of `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` can't be casted to `EnumSet<Enumtype>`.

Comment: @Robert: But `EnumSet` has not methods, so there is not much point of having that type. Everything you can do with `EnumSet` you can also do with `Set`.